# AngularJS http call (complete syntax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I'm new to AngularJS and 
I needed to know if we can make a jQuery like Ajax call in Angular and wanted to know it's complete syntax, 
if anyone could help me making the whole code syntax.

Example in jQuery I could do something like -

```
$.ajax(
{
      url: 'someURL',
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      data:
      {
          something: something,
          somethingelse: somethingelse
      },
      beforeSend: function()
      {
          $('#someID').addClass('spinner');
      },
      success: function(response)
      {
          $('#someID').removeClass('spinner');

          console.log(response);              
      },
      complete: function(response)
      {
           $('#someID').removeClass('spinner');

           console.log(response);
      },
      error: function (errorResp)
      {    
           console.log(errorResp);
      }
});
```

Now here's what I found out on making http call in Angular,
Need help in building the complete syntax, with all possible options -

```
var req = {

       method: 'POST',
       url: 'someURL',
       headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined
       },
       data: {
             //goes in the Payload, if I'm not wrong 
             something: 'something' 
       },
       params:{
              //goes as Query Params
              something: 'something',
              somethingElse: 'somethingElse'
       }
}

$http(req)
.then(function()
{
   //success function    
}, 
function()
{
   //Error function    
});
```

now what if I want to attach a spinner on some id in the BeforeSend function like in jQuery and remove the spinner in success, 
What is the Angular's way as a like to like for BeforeSend or making the http call async?

Comment: why do you need a `beforeSend` at all? Just set up the spinner before the `$http` call (or even after which will also work because the call is asynchronous) and remove it in `.then` function?

Comment: Yes, I could make temporary fixes no doubt, i just wanted to know if there is any standard way in Angular like jQuery has.

Comment: it is not a temporary fix, it is a very normal way of doing what you want. I personally find the jQuery way to be an overkill. There is absolutely no need for any `beforeSend` function.

Comment: @Aniruddharaje that's not for just showing spinner in that. bedoreSend has other actual usage.

Answer (score 1):

Angular even let you control this better :). Two ways can be chosen here:

**1.  Wrapping $http**

You can write for each request with by **using a wrapper of $http** which will add some methods before and after you made request

```
app.factory('httpService',function($http){
    function beginRequest() {};
    function afterRequest() {};
    return {
        makeRequest: function(requestConfig){
             beginRequest();
             return $http(requestConfig).then(function(result){
                 afterRequest(result);
             });
        }
    }      
})
```

Then each time you can call this function to make a request. This is not new.

**2. Using interceptor**

Angular has a better way to handle for all request. It use a **new concept named 'interceptor'**. You write your interceptor as a normal service and push one or many interceptors into $http service and depend on type of interceptor, it will be called each time your request happen. Look at this picture to think about interceptor:
[image]

Some common task for interceptor can be: Add/remove a loading icon, add some more decorator to your http config such as token key, validate request, validate responded data, recover some request...

Here is example of a interceptor that add a token key into headers of a request

```
app.service('APIInterceptor', function($rootScope, UserService) {
    var service = this;

    service.request = function(config) { 
        var currentUser = UserService.getCurrentUser(),
            access_token = currentUser ? currentUser.access_token : null;

        if (access_token) {
            config.headers.authorization = access_token;
        }
        return config;
    };

    service.responseError = function(response) {
        return response;
    };
})
```

Then add interceptor to your $http:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('APIInterceptor');
}]);
```

Now all request will be added a token key to header. cool right?

See [here](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/) for more information:

Answer (score 0):

there is eveyrthing here to help with your question :https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q  http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/

Answer (score 0):

> $http functions are async by default.

And regarding the beforesend function, you could wrap the http call in a function and add the spinner just before making the call and remove it in the success call back. Something like this,

```
var makeHttpRequest = function(){
   $('#someID').addClass('spinner');
   $http(req).then(function(){
     $('#someID').removeClass('spinner');
     //rest processing for success callback
   },function(){
     $('#someID').removeClass('spinner');
     //Error callback
   });
}
```

Comment: so how would I make the http call synchronous if I need to?

Comment: $http calls are asynchronous by default. You could make it synchronous by the implementation of $q. and making the wrapper function return a promise once the $http call is completed.

You could read about $q from here [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Answer (score 0):

The way I have implemented complex get and post in my angular application is as below:

Create a CRUDService as below:

```
yourApp.service('CRUDService', function ($q, $http) {
    this.post = function (value, uri) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: uri,
            data: value
        });
        return request;
    }

    this.get = function (uri) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "get",
            url: uri
        });
        return request;
    }
});
```

As you can see this service simply returns a get/post object. Somewhere in my controller I use this service as below:

```
$('#exampleButton').button("loading");  //set the element in loading/spinning state here
var getObj = CRUDService.get("/api/get/something");
getObj.then(function(data){
    //do something
    $('#exampleButton').button("reset"); //reset element here
}, function(err){
    //handle error
    $('#exampleButton').button("loading"); //reset element here
});

$('#exampleButton').button("loading");  //set the element in loading/spinning state here
var postObj = CRUDService.post(postData,"/api/get/something");
postObj.then(function(data){
    //do something
    $('#exampleButton').button("reset"); //reset element here
}, function(err){
    //handle error
    $('#exampleButton').button("loading"); //reset element here
});
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The `http` call is async - it returns a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) that you can then handle with the `try()` and `catch()` methods. You can simply wrap your calls i.e.

```
function makeRequest() {
  $scope.showSpinner = true;
  $http
    .get('http://www.example.com')
    .then(function (response) {
      $scope.showSpinner = false;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      $scope.showSpinner = false;
    });
}
```

If you would however like you use familiar syntax akin to `jQuery` then you can push your own custom interceptors. This will allow you intercept the requests and response and do whatever you want. In the below example we call functions if they are defined.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .config(appConfig)
  .factory('HttpInterceptors', httpInterceptors)
  .controller('MyController', myController);

// app config
appConfig.$inject = ['$httpProvider'];

function appConfig($httpProvider) {
  // add out interceptors to the http provider
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpInterceptors');
}

// http interceptor definition
function httpInterceptors() {
  return {
    request: function(request) {
      if (angular.isFunction(request.beforeSend)) {
        request.beforeSend(); 
      }
      return request;
    },
    response: function(response) {
      if (angular.isFunction(response.config.onComplete)) {
        response.config.onComplete(); 
      }
      return response; 
    }
  }
}

// controlller
myController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout'];

function myController($scope, $http, $timeout) {

  $scope.showSpinner = false;
  
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dart-lang/test/master/LICENSE',
    beforeSend: function() {
      $scope.showSpinner = true;
    },
    onComplete: function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        console.log('done');
        $scope.showSpinner = false;
      }, 1000);
    }})
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log('success');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error('fail');
    });
}
```

```css
.spinner {
 background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='MyController'>
  <div ng-class='{spinner: showSpinner}'>
    Hello World!
  </div>
</div>
```